# How to get rid of the keyboard when i tap on the textbox for Win Phone 8

Tags: xaml, windows-phone-8

I currently developing a simple application for win8 phone. In my application, i have a textbox and what i try to do is when i try to tap on the textbox, i will navigate user to another page. But everytime i tap on the textbox, the keyboard will show up for less than one second before the application is navigated to the other page. May i know how to get rid of the keyboard? Thanks

```
private void MyTextBox_Tap_1(object sender, System.Windows.Input.GestureEventArgs e)
    {
        NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri("/MainPage.xaml", UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute));
    }
```

Comment: if i were you i would set `IsReadOnly="True"`

Comment: Yes Readonly true will work, but I have a question for you, why would you want to do this in the first place? Please explain what do you want to achieve, because this is not a standard UI experience and user will get confused. If you want to navigate to another page then use Button, image or any other control.

Comment: This is also a way to do it: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/silverlight_sdk/archive/2010/07/02/programmatically-dismiss-the-sip-keyboard-in-windows-phone-silverlight-app.aspx But I agree with the comment above, why do you want to do that? Maybe we can help with alternatives =)

Comment: ya, thats work. However when i set IsReadOnly="True", the textbox will gray out....i don't want the textbox to gray out.

@sunil5715: After user tap on the textbox, user will redirect to the MainPage.xaml and then user will select a item from the page. The selected item will show up in the textbox. Just like a comboBox

Comment: You could always position a transparent `Button` or even a transparent Rectangle with an EventHandler over the `TextBox` to grab the click event instead of the TextBox. Or you could edit a `TextBox` to remove the Disabled state object that appears so it doesn't gray out.